# Open Outlook inbox from my app

Tags: url, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to launch Outlook from my WP8 app. I know that I can launch Outlook composer using the mailto: URL scheme, but that is not what I want. My server have sent an e-mail to the user and I want to help them go directly to the inbox where the mail I sent should appear.

Is there a protocol for just opening Outlook inbox and not open the compose dialog?

Comment: i think you cannot access outlook mails from your app. Microsoft restricts this future for security purpose. This is as far i know

Comment: Thank for the reply but to clarify: I am not intending to access the inbox, just open the application "Outlook" so that the user can see his/her inbox, so there is no security issues involved.

Comment: You'd have to know the URI for the mail application.  Then there's the question of which inbox to open, since there can be multiple email boxes - which complicates the matter of what the URI is...  Good question, but I don't know that it can be done, but if it can, it would depend on figuring out how the OS assigns the URI to the mailbox.

Comment: Opening the list of mailboxes would be sufficient (so the user can click on the desired one)